# Tkinter canvas.create_window update window position

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a tool with Pyton Tkinter where modules can be displayed onto a canvas. These modules are represented by a class with position and size attributes as back-end and a rectangular frame on a canvas as front-end. When a new module is created, my program draws a default frame with a certain size and position on the canvas (front-end) and a creates an instance of the module class (back-end). The user gets to see a popup in which the module-instance attributes can be updated, and the frame position and size should be updated with it.

However, displaying a frame inside a canvas requires the moduleWindow = canvas.create_window(x,y,frame) method, and the position of the frame is defined by this (x,y). I have been updating the frame size using frame.config(), but how to update the position? There is no method to do this for the canvas_window moduleWindow? (e.g.  moduleWindow.config(__x = updatedModule.position[0], __y = updatedModule.position[1]))

```
    def update_moduleFrame(self,updatedModule, moduleFrame, moduleWindow):
        moduleFrame.config(width=updatedModule.size[0], height=updatedModule.size[1])
```

Comment: Moving items on a Canvas is done via the `.move()` or `.coords()` methods of the Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the coordinates of a window with the `coords` method.

```
...
canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
frame_id = tk.canvas.create_window(0,0, ...)
...
tk.canvas.coords(frame_id, 100, 100)
...
```